# Как с помощью Flexbox выровнять весь контент по центру?

Tags: html, css

Есть блок в котором содержится картинка и под ней текст.
Как выровнять этот контент по центру?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: space-between;
```

не помогает.

Comment: `align-items: center`

Comment: Картинки тогда становятся тоже по центру но слева от текста. А мне нужно чтобы они были над текстом.

Comment: каким образом они становятся слева, это у вас что то с версткой. Никогда таких проблем не было

Answer (score 8):

Укажите направление для выстраивания элементов и все заработает:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container.demo {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container demo">
  <img src="https://satyr.io/40x40/2">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```